# Input field not working on windows build version

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two input fields, this is how it looks in the editor:
[image: Working example]

In the editor everything works great but when I build the game (to windows) the input field looks like this:

[image: Not working example]

And in the build version I can't input any text either. I am using Unity 2020.1

Can you help?

Comment: Maybe your input field is not interectable? Check it in an inspector

Comment: It's interactable, I checked, and as I said in the editor everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem!
The resolution on the editor and the resolution on the build weren't the same, and the font size was too big for the build resolution so it "disappeared" out of the input field. I just set the editor resolution to the build resolution and lowered the font size